# using a Random as index in ArrayList, not moving if used before

Tags: java, random, arraylist

i'm trying to do something like the TSP in java and i have a problem with generating paths.
I want to choose my next "city" with a random integer but if the integer is used before i want to re-randomize it and not to move the index of the loop anyfurther until the index is unique.

This is what i have in code.

```
int citynum = 10;
double maxdist = 0;
int ants = 10;
Random random = new Random(500);
Random ran = new Random(citynum);
double dist;
double pair = 0;

ArrayList<TestCity> cities = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<Integer> path = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> used = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<Integer> bestpath = new ArrayList<>();


for (int i = 0; i < citynum; i++) {
    dist = random.nextDouble();
    cities.add(new TestCity(dist, i + 1));
}

/**
 * generate paths
 */
for (int i = 0; i < ants; i++) {
    for (int k = 0; k < cities.size(); k++) {
        int j = ran.nextInt();
        int[] usedNum = new int[citynum];


        if (cities.get(j).isVisited() == false) {    
            cities.get(j).setVisited(true);
            pair += cities.get(j).getDistance();
            path.add(cities.get(j).getName());
        }
    }
    used.add(path);
    if(pair<maxdist){
        maxdist=pair;
        bestpath = path;
    }
}


System.out.println(path);
```

My problem is at the spt where i'm using the random in the for() loops. I tried using an Array of integers t keep the randoms used but i just got lost in the loops.
Can anyone tell me how to do this? Or perhaps a simpler way without using some big-time-published algrithm? I don't understand all that math.

Comment: How is that going to solve your TSP?

Comment: well i'm not actually doing the full-on TSP, just an example of it. It's crappy i know but i don't really get AI and i have to deliver a project for grade in school so i'm just getting the distance from the path i create and use the smallest sum as my ideal path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the number of cities is known - which seems to be the case-, you can fill another `ArrayList<Integer>` with the numbers `0` to `cities.size()-1` (the maximum index), and then use `java.util.Collections.shuffle(List<?>)` to randomly shuffle the indexes. Then you can iterate over this list from beginning to end and you'll get each index only once.

For the next loop you don't need to clear and refill the index list, just call `Collections.shuffle()` on it again to get another order.

`Collection.shuffle(List<?>)` works directly on the list by re-ordering the entries on a random base, and should be pretty fast.

Comment: thanks that worked great. I changed my code by adding a loop for creating a new path before start using said path and it stops in the loop. This is what i did:
int temp=0;
        for(int i=0; i<10; i++){
        Collections.shuffle(path);
        while(used.contains(path)==true){
            Collections.shuffle(path);
        }
        used.add(path);

Any ideas of what i am doing wrong? It only prints 1 path and stays at the while loop forever.

Comment: Maybe you could edit your question to reflect those changes. Just a guess: I don't think that `List.contains(List)` works as you expect - it compares the object references and not the content of the entries (`path` will remain the same object even after being shuffled, because only its content is changed). Instead you need a custom method to check if a list of lists contains a given list, something like this: https://gist.github.com/jcoder/8248874

Answer (score 1):

Use a HashSet, when you call for a random number/index. Say you got the random index x. You now check if it's in the HashSet. If it is not, you add it to the HashSet and you can use it as an index. If it is already in the HashSet, you don't use it, and you just call for getting another random index y.

Comment: It sounds like a practical approach to store the used indices. However this might cause some runtime inconveniences when nearly all indices have been used and random needs to be executed very often to find an unused index.